# Error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. (APT0000)

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am new to xamarin studio.
I have added all the required packages corresponding to the target API 23 to my android xamarin studio project, set it to the right target API 23 but am still being haunted by these errors in the image below. Any help rendered will be greatly appreciated

[Image contains errors from an android xamarin studio project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4QsJ.png)

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild all

Answer (score 1):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using support library v23, you need to compile against Android SDK of v23.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against v22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.